# Delete all files except for 2 folders and 1 file

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems

I have a directory that has tons of files, and they are named with GUID names.

There are only 3 files in there that I want to keep, and I don't want to move them or anything as the OS might be using them.

How can I delete ALL files in a folder, except for 2 folders and 1 file?

Comment: Select all, hold `Ctrl`, unselect those that you want to keep, and delete the rest? Or do you want a command line solution?

Comment: Ubuntu (or Linux in general) can deal with files that are being moved while they are in use (unless you move them to a different partition). So: `mkdir ../tmp ; mv dir1 dir2 file1 ../tmp ; rm * ; mv ../tmp/* . ; rmdir ../tmp`. If there are subdirs, make that `rm -r *`.

Comment: this is on a vps server.